# C# Blazor Micro Front end framework code samples

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly, micro-frontend

I am looking at ways to make separate deployable "modules" in Blazor Web Assembly. Let's say you have 5 major components like Home, Products, Sale and Admin. Each of these would be separate deployable modules. Is there a way I can achieve this using Blazor?

I can make a project where I am using Razox dll and lazy loading them. But I would need something that is deployed separately too. Any ideas? I did look at some talks on "Piral" and Florian guy but most of the samples are not working.

https://github.com/smapiot/Piral.Blazor